# Can I trigger an event on a GWT widget using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, gwt

I am trying to automate a website that was built using GWT. My automation uses jQuery to select an appropriate element and then call the jQuery click() function to trigger a click event.

However, the expected action doesn't take place. Clicking the element with the mouse brings up a dialog box, but using jQuery does nothing.  If I use jQuery to add a new click handler, I see the new handler executed in both cases, but the original handler only in the "real" click case.

Stepping into the Javascript code, I see very complicated code dealing with stack depth, leading me to think doing this automation may not be directly possible.

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically fire an event on a GWT-generated element? Or should this be working normally, and this site uses uniquely complicated code?

Edit: The code I'm using is quite simple:

```
var searchButton = jQuery('div.GH1CUEEFLB.GH1CUEEMLB:first');
if (searchButton && searchButton.length > 0) {
    searchButton.click();
}
```

Stepping through the code shows that it selects the correct element, and proceeds to call click().  The existing event handler for the widget, according to Chrome's debugger, is complicated. Stepping through the process leads to a rabbit hole that is quite difficult to follow:

```
function(){
    var stackIndex, returnTemp;
    $stack_0[stackIndex = ++$stackDepth_0] = null;
    try {
        returnTemp = entry0(($location_0[stackIndex] = '57' , jsFunction), this, arguments);
        $stackDepth_0 = stackIndex - 1;
        return returnTemp;
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw $location_0[stackIndex] = '63' , e;
    }
    $stackDepth_0 = stackIndex - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case was to trigger the click event on one of the child elements within the div.  The event handler was attached to a particular div surrounding all the components of the button (label, icon, borders, etc).  Triggering the event on that parent element did nothing.  However, if I instead selected one of the leaf nodes in that subtree (say, the label itself), then triggering the click event brought up the dialog box as desired.

I guess the event handler's code was actively determining the exact element that triggered the event, but was not expecting the parent div to be that trigger source.

```
var searchButton = jQuery('div.GH1CUEEJT:first');
```

The above selects the leaf node upon which to trigger the event, even though the parent node 'div.GH1CUEEFLB.GH1CUEEMLB' held the event handler.